# Make changing form (like draft/finish) on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to make forms 
which has three scenes

1.input view (which has 'confirm' button)
2.draft check view (which has 'send' button)
3.send view

in method 1 you can input the data then click 'confirm' button

the system write the data in DB as draft.

in method 2 you see the data and confirm then push  'send' button

the system write the flg 'confirmed'

these are my code.

it works well method 1 but if I push 'send' button in method2.
it doesn't go.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
```

My idea is something wrong??

```
public function writeEvalStudentAction(Request $request,$keyStr){

    ...

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($evalStudent)
    ->add('commentToStudent')
    ->add('confirm','submit')->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request); 

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        if ($form->has('send')){
            if ($form->get('send')->isClicked()){

        //set confirm flg then shows thanks screen.

            $evalStudent->setConfirmed(true);
            $em->persist($evalStudent);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:confirmedEvalStudent.html.twig');
            }
         }
        if ($form->has('confirm')){
            if ($form->get('confirm')->isClicked()){

        // write in the db as draft.
            $evalStudent->setCommentToStudent($form->get('commentToStudent')->getData());

            $em->persist($evalStudent);
            $em->flush();

            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($evalStudent)->add('send','submit')->getForm();
            return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:checkEvalStudent.html.twig',
                array('form' => $form->createView()));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('AcmeMemberBundle:Default:writeEvalStudent.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it up in 4 controller actions with 4 separate routes. Whereas route2 and route3 require the id of your draft object in the routing parameters.

Make the form1 from step 1 point to step2.
In step2 validate the form and if it is ok insert to db and get your id, then show form2 which points to step 3, if not show form1 with form errors.

Same for step2->step3 and step3->step4.

In step 4 you convert your draft to a final object and persist it and remove the draft.

Comment: It also is the good way though ,is it impossible to do everything in one Controller? almost there I think...

Comment: Not impossible, but making things harder for you, for no real gain.

Comment: I have made the controller separate one already. However my program has this kind of things many times. so I would like to make my code more smaller.

Comment: If you want your code to be smaller just write it all on one line. ;)
What I'm saying is smaller isn't always better and if you crunch it all into one extra long controller action it makes your life harder later on.

Comment: OK I separate the code in two controllers step1+step2 and step3+step4. try to keep things simple a.m.a.p. thanks alot